# How to centre a shape in css

Tags: css, position, css-position, positioning, shapes

I am creating a website screen as a temporary "coming soon page". I have a circle behind some text. The text always seems to be centred on the page no matter the size of the browser window but the circle seems to move locations on different sizes. Is there a way for me to have the circle be completely behind the text?

Being new to code I followed some tutorials but none seemed to work

Heres the website in question: http://unixcast.com/

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #19181D;
}
.circle{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#313247 0%,#19181D 30%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 35%;
}
.circle:before,
.cirlce:after{
    content: '';
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FF849D 0%,#FF849D 5%, #2D2133 25%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-filter:blur(7px);
    z-index: -1;
}
.cirlce:after{
    width: 415px;
    top: 35%;
    -webkit-filter:blur(14px);
    opacity: .3;
}
.unixcast{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
.msg{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <span class="unixcast"> UNIXCAST </span>
    <span class="msg">IS COMING SOON!</span>
    <span class="notifymsg"> GET NOTIFIED WHEN IT'S READY</span>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="email" name="ENTER YOUR EMAIL"/>
        <button>NOTIFY ME</button>
    </span>
</body>
</html>>
```

I expected to see the circle directly behind the text but it seems to move with different size screens and windows

Comment: please post also your html code

Comment: is that alright

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please write this css for you circle class

```
.circle {
     height: 400px;
     width: 400px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: linear-gradient(#313247 0%,#19181D 30%);
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     margin: auto;
     top: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
 }
```